# CSS Sticky Footer Failure

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am trying to get a Sticky Footer to work, and have currently tried the following css:

```
 #footer {
        width:920px;
        height:208px;
        font-size:10px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-image:url(images/grad.png);
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        padding:0 20px;
        clear:both;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:-208px;
 }

 body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:13px;
        color:#333333;
        background-repeat:repeat-x;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
 }

 #wrap {
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
        min-height:100%;
        height: 100%;
 }


    #content {
        width:892px;
        float:left;
        border-left:4px solid white;
        border-right:4px solid white;
        padding:15px 0px 15px 20px;
        background-image:url(images/sidebar_bg.png);
        position:relative;
        padding-bottom:143px;
    }
```

I have had to reduce the #content padding-bottom, so it would fit. But I am still having issues. Firstly, There is too much space at the bottom of longer pages (see - http://bellbird.redgraphic.co.uk/headteacher/ ) Secondly, on a shorter page the footer doesnt scroll up when the browser window is resized (see - http://bellbird.redgraphic.co.uk/school-council/ )

Sticky footers always seem to be an issue, so I must be missing a trick.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Lewis

Comment: use postion:fixed and bottom:0; for your css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[usefull link here.](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) This one helped me with the same issue.

CSS mark-up:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

HTML mark-up:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think `position:absolute` not keep footer in bottom always! many issue arise when you `resize window`.

Comment: @Sarfaraz ... you have a example for that?

Comment: I've tried many times when i make websites and scrollbars visible then it will not work when you `resized window` footer always gone upside according to give position and am damn sure about it

Comment: Well use this for a while now. Tried some of my websites with resizing the window. Still on the bottom...
Its not just the footer position that counts with this method, also the on of the elemnts obve it...

Comment: [Make sure you update your answer with some actual code.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @DiederikEEn but you know when `scrollbar` visible in body then footer goes up in `scroll` for this we have to handle it and make a `content div` above `footer div` if `scrollbar` come in the `content div` then everything will be fine

Comment: @Sarfaraz cant follow you there m8

Answer (score 0):

use this css instead of your

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   height:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
...
</footer>
```

css:

```
html, body {height:100%;}
.wrap {min-height:100%; height:auto !important; margin-bottom:-100px;}
.inner-wrap {padding-bottom:100px;}
footer {height:100px;}
```